# calculating $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n} \right)^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I was asked in an exercise to check whether a series converges or not and while doing so I got the following limit to solve:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n} \right)^{n}$$

I did the following in order so solve it:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n} \right)^{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1-3}{n} \right)^{n} =\frac{1}{e^2}$$

The series that I was trying to check if it was convergent or not turned out to be convergent and that implies that:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n} \right)^{n} < 1$$
Which is what I got. But the thing is that this is the first time that I tried to calculate a Limit superior. So is the following step correct or is it wrong and I just got lucky and got the same result:

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n-3}{n} \right)^{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1-3}{n} \right)^{n}$$

Comment: The argument is correct, only it should be $\frac{2}{e^2}$ instead $\frac{1}{e^2}$.

Comment: The calculation of the limsup is not correct, the second term should have $2n$ instead of $n$. The answer $1/e^2$ is correct though.

Comment: Is there any rule to turn a lim sup into a regular lim or it allays depend in the specific lim sup we are trying to calculate? @Sam

Comment: @Eduude limsup is the sup of all limit points, so there will always be a *subsequence* the converges to it, but there's no simple rule to find that subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^{2n}-3}{2n} \right)^{2n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{e^2}$$
And 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}-3}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+1} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{4}{2n+1} \right)^{2n+1} = \frac{1}{e^4}$$

Since any subsequence will have infinitely many even or infinitely odd terms, those are the only two possible limit points, so the limsup is the first one.